# Can a UIKit application co-exist with a Unity game as a single application?

Tags: unity

I have a typical UIKit application with three buttons - one opens an RSS feed in a `UITableView`, the second opens some kind of gallery view, and the third opens a Unity 3D game.

Is it possible and how easy it is to support both in one application?

Comment: relevant http://millipede.com.au/blog/bridging-unity-and-the-ios-sdk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be improbably difficult. Unity is not a standalone view wholly contained within a `UIView` subclass instance; if it were, this would be easy enough, you'd just add the view as a subview when you wanted to activate the Unity game and remove it when you were done (or use any number of similar `UIView` manipulation techniques).

Unity, however, expects to be the authoritative source of the application's behavior, so trying to host a Unity game within a "regular" iOS application is going to result in you fighting that behavior and spending a lot of effort for minimal gain.

You should consider implementing the behavior the other way around: have a Unity game which occasionally defers to some Objective-C based UIKit code via [native plugins](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x/), which basically involves:

- creating an Xcode project or target that contains the Objective-C code for manipulating the desired `UIView` objects.
- conforming to the Unity plugin API so you have an entry point into your plugin from the rest of your Unity project.
- invoking that entry point as-needed.

If you are not keen on building all that yourself, something like the [iOS bridge](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/188912-iOS-Bridge-Unity-with-UIKit), or just resign yourself to building your GUI with Unity's built-in primitives.

Comment: Took more than a year to finally get an answer. Thanks a lot for the useful info :)